# From mysql_num_rows to mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, database

If I am using mysql_num_rows, so I would only be able to use a number for retrieving data(Eg. ID of 1 will retrieve data from row with ID 1) ?

Is it possible to retrieve data using a character/word (Eg. Using email to retrieve data from the row with the same email)?

```
// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["email"])) {
$email = $_GET['email'];

// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE email = $email");

if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $product = array();

        $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $result["name"];
        $product["email"] = $result["email"];

        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["product"] = array();

        array_push($response["product"], $product);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
  } else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response); 
}?>
```

Comment: You needs quotes in your email `email = '".$email."'"` And stop using mysql instead using `mysqli or PDO`

Comment: @Saty, not need quotes for email.

Comment: do you guys have any idea on how can i do it?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava why is not needed??

Comment: @Saty, because emailID doesn't contains spaces & quotes are usually for spaced strings.

Comment: why do people keep downvoting?

Comment: @TanChongKai, I still didn't understand what do you want to do ?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava I want to use an email from my android app to retrieve the data from the row with the same email in the database.

Comment: So, whats the problem ? You are doing the same in your query!!

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava yeah but the data don't appear to be showing on my android app. Is my php code correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91724/discussion-between-tan-chong-kai-and-harshit-shrivastava).

Comment: Check if the data exists against the emailID